# $f$ is analytic on $D$ except an essential singularity $z_0$. Can one deduce that
$\int\int_D|f(z)|^p d x d y=\infty$
For all $p>0$?

Tags: complex-analysis

$z_0$ is an essential singularity of $f$,$D$ is a disc centered at the origion and contains $z_0$.$f$ is analytic on $D$ except $z_0$.

Can one deduce that
$$\int\int_D|f(z)|^p d x d y=\infty$$
For all $p>0$ ?

Comment: somebody gave me  a hint : just use the Harnack Iequality and show that the ∞-Norm of $f$ on $B(z,r)$ is smaller than $C$ times the $L^2$ Norm on $B(z,2r)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WLOG, $z_0=0.$ Let $D=\{0<|z|<R\}$ and suppose $\int_D |f|^p\,dA < \infty$ for some $p>0.$ Recall that $|f|^p$ is subharmonic on $D.$ Thus for $z\in D,$

$$|f(z)|^p \le \frac{1}{\pi(|z|/2)^2} \int_{|w-z|<|z|/2}|f(w)|^p\,dA(w) \le \frac{C}{|z|^2},$$

where $C$ is a constant independent of $z.$ Thus $|f(z)|\le \dfrac{C}{|z|^{2/p}}$ in $D.$ This implies $f$ has at most a pole at $0,$ contradiction.

Comment: thank you very much